# How to filter "Yes/No (check box)" field from lookup list using pnp/rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, modern-experience, pnp

How to filter "Yes/No (check box)" field from lookup list using PnP/REST API?

I can filter other columns with different types but not able to filter "Yes/No (check box)" field.

It is showing below error message:

> The query to field 'LookupList/LookupField' is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

Extending Yes/No field using lookup columns is **not supported** in SharePoint. So, you will not be able fetch or add the filter on Yes/No field from lookup list.

**Supported Column Types**:

- Single line of text
- Number
- Date and Time

**Unsupported Column Types**:

- Multiple lines of text
- Currency
- Person or Group
- Calculated
- Hyperlink or Picture
- Custom Columns
- Yes/No
- Choice
- Lookup

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.