# Column with lookup doesn't show the selected list columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, modern-experience, list-column

I am having a trouble with lookup column from one list to other list, the columns are not showing in selection.

I have list called Business Case and list Status report, I would like to add some of the columns from Business case to SP using lookup and select the columns I would like to display the data.

[image]

Unfortunately I cant see all created columns in the lists, as showing in the picture.

Can someone advice me, why the created columns are not visible on lookup fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known behavior in SharePoint.

SharePoint lookup columns only support below column types:

- Single line of text
- Number
- Date and Time

**Similar thread**: [How to filter "Yes/No (check box)" field from lookup list using pnp/rest api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286069/how-to-filter-yes-no-check-box-field-from-lookup-list-using-pnp-rest-api/286070#286070)

**Documentation**: [Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

Comment: thanks, didnt know this...

Comment: So am I to understand that lookup columns are not like relationships after all?  For example, if I have an Assets table and want to look up a User ID--a number in the assets table and "key" in the users table) and then get the users name (different column) then I... can't?  Because the name isn't a number?  Name isn't populating off this lookup.